# Did any of the Weasley kids get new dress robes for the Yule Ball?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Goblet of Fire*, Ron is appalled when Molly sends him his dress robes for the Yule Ball. Apparently, they smelled like Ron's Great Aunt Tessie and looked like they sashayed right off *The Love Boat*. Ruffled tuxedos were popular in the 70s, of course. Anyhow, right, Ron got the scrapings of the barrel when it came to dress robes. But what about the other Weasley kids who were attending Hogwarts at the time of the Yule Ball?

**Q: Did *any* of the Weasley kids receive new dress robes for the Yule Ball? Or, if not brand new dress robes, robes that were at least in presentable condition and of a modern style?**

Comment: As far as I can see the only (book) answer comes by way of omission - presumably the robes were at least presentable, or they'd have been remarked upon. Possibly Bill and Charlies hand-me-downs? Or Molly prioritised her 16 year olds dress robes over her 14 year old, which would make sense. Gred and Forge gotta be lookin' fine for the ladies...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could not find any quotes on dress robes used by the twins. But based on Mrs. Weasley's statement, all of her kids got secondhand clothes. It could be Ron's bad luck that there weren't any good robes of his size.

> “Don’t be so silly,” said Mrs. Weasley. “You’ve got to have dress robes, they’re on your list! I got some for Harry too... show him, Harry...”
>
> In some trepidation, Harry opened the last parcel on his camp bed. It wasn’t as bad as he had expected, however; his dress robes didn’t have any lace on them at all - in fact, they were more or less the same as his school ones, except that they were bottle green instead of black.
>
> “I thought they’d bring out the color of your eyes, dear,” said Mrs. Weasley fondly.
>
> “Well, they’re okay!” said Ron angrily, looking at Harry’s robes. “Why couldn’t I have some like that?”
>
> **“Because... well, I had to get yours secondhand, and there wasn’t a lot of choice!” said Mrs. Weasley, flushing.**
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 10, Mayhem at the Ministry</sup></sub>

Digging up bit of history to substantiate my points:

> “That lot won’t come cheap,” said George, with a quick look at his parents. “Lockhart’s books are really expensive...”
>
> “Well, we’ll manage,” said Mrs. Weasley, but she looked worried. “I expect we’ll be able to pick up a lot of Ginny’s things secondhand.”
>
> Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4, At Flourish and Blotts

The Weasley kids normally got secondhand stuff.

> “The diary,” said Riddle. “My diary. Little Ginny’s been writing in it for months and months, telling me all her pitiful worries and woes — how her brothers tease her, how she had to come to school with secondhand robes and books, how —” Riddle’s eyes glinted “— how she didn’t think famous, good, great Harry Potter would ever like her...”
>
> Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 17, The Heir of Slytherin

Answer (score 6):

Well, Percy certainly did - although, seeing as he was, by that time, a fully grown adult, earning his own wage; and seeing as he was on official ministry business - it could be argued that he doesn't really count:

> Harry took the hint and sat down next to Percy, who was wearing brand-new, navy-blue dress robes, and an expression of great smugness.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - p.361 - Bloomsbury - chapter 23, *The Yule Ball*

Apart from that, I've skimmed through *The Yule Ball* and the best I can give you is this: All three of the other Weasley children are mentioned in passing when they're at the Yule Ball and their clothing isn't explicitly remarked upon. It's not much, but it might suggest that their robes weren't *as* bad. (Edit: credit to DavidS for having more-or-less the same idea. Sorry, didn't notice your comment, there.)

Comment: This is such a great tidbit you dug up -- I *really* debated between your answer and **Vishvesh's**. I ultimately went with the other answer, because technically I said "the Weasley kids who were at Hogwarts" at the time of the Yule Ball. But I can offer you 10 througuh a +1. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you @Slytherincess :) You're welcome! So you did, I must have missed the detail about actually attending Hogwarts. Ah well, I certainly don't begrudge Vishvesh the 15 points and the green tick of approval.

Answer (score 1):

**Presentable and modern style:** Yes

I don't know if you'll accept the movie version but take a look at the dress robes of Fred and compare them to Ron's:

[image: Fred's dress robes]

[image: Ron's dress robes]

As you can see Fred's are much more modern looking than Ron's. Whether these were brand new or not is another matter but they at least look as though they're from a more recent time than Ron's.

Comment: Didn't Fred and George make some money off the Quiditch World Cup? I know some of it was fake, but still...

Comment: @Zikato If I recall correctly they stashed that away for 'research' purposes.  In any event, even if that was the source of the finances for their more modern clothes, there were still some Weasleys with modern-ish clothes

Comment: is that supposed to be Fred? Why doesn't he have red hair?

Comment: @user13267 Interesting point!  I'd say it's just the light or something!

Comment: @Zikato At the Quidditch World Cup, Ron gathers some of the leprechaun gold - but it's not just fake, it literally disappears after a short time (few hours). Whether Fred and George did, too, we don't know, but if they did it would have vanished. They did, however, win a bet with Ludo Bagman, but he initially paid them in leprechaun gold and then, when confronted, eventually refused to pay them at all. This was a minor sub-plot. Since they bet their entire savings, they actually lost money at the Quidditch World Cup

Comment: Although, one does get the feeling it was a factor in Harry's decision to give them his Triwizard winnings, so, in a very roundabout way...

Comment: Sorry, I no will do the movies, but I will applaud you for the picture of Ron -- it's pretty funny :))

Comment: @Slytherincess well, if I couldn't give you an answer that you were looking for, at least I've given you a laugh :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why Fred and George's dress robes looked quit modern was because they were once worn by Charlie and Bill. And since the Weasleys had enough money at the time they were new before they were worn by Fred or George.

[image]

And who said Ginny's dress was new? Maybe they were her mother’s or she borrowed them from a friend.

[image]

Percy had new dress robes which is proved as follows:

> Harry took the hint and sat down next to Percy, who was wearing brand-new, navy-blue dress robes, and an expression of great smugness.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - p.361 - Bloomsbury - chapter 23, “The Yule Ball”

So I think Charlie Bill and Percy had new dress robes.